# How to verify Office 365 Email DNS entries using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-cmdlet

I have a PowerShell script that uses the Active Directory cmdlet

**Get-AzureADDomainServiceConfigurationRecord -Name** *domain-name*

to retrieve the required DNS settings for a custom domain that I have added to Office 365.  The script then calls my Domain Hosting Provider to apply those DNS settings.

Now I would like to tell Office 365 to go and check for those DNS entries and move the enrolled domain from an (as shown in the Office 365 Admin portal) "incomplete setup" to a "healthy" status so I can use it.

Can someone point me at the cmdlet to do this DNS entries verification step? I have spent a lot of time searching, but to no avail.

Thanks very much,
Simon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to Microsoft Support and further research, I have concluded that verifying the DNS settings for a custom domain using PowerShell is not possible. You must use the Admin Portal to get the domain into a 'healthy' state so that it can be used for mailbox addresses. I'd love to be proven wrong, so please post if you find a way!

Answer (score 0):

From the [AzureAD module documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#domains), "Domains" section, you have `Confirm-AzureADDomain -Name "mydomain.com"`.

Comment: Thanks @anto418 for the reply. However, `Confirm-AzureADDomain` is used to verify ownership of the custom domain after you have placed a specific DNS record on it that you obtain using `Get-AzureADDomainVerificationDnsRecord`. It does not validate the service DNS records obtained from `Get-AzureADDomainServiceConfigurationRecord` have been set-up correctly, which is what I need. Any other ideas? Thanks.